# Combine multiple replace-regexp to a program

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

I am working on cleaning files with multiple regex-replacement

```
<<.*>>                  -> ""
\([[:alpha:]]\)\*       -> \1 ;; patters as pragram* to program
\*\([[:alpha:]]\)       -> \1 ;; patters as *program to program
\*/\([[:alpha:]]\)      -> \1
;;and so on
```

On every single file, I have to invoke `replace-regexp` various times.

How could combine these regex search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To an extent, `M-x whitespace-cleanup` has similar requirements, that is, cleanup base on multiple conditions. It should be possible to use [(emacs) Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html), but I am not familiar with it. Once you have some knowledge in Emacs Lisp, you can solve the problem easily, for example, the following cleanups leading and trailing spaces, you can add your regexp and their replacement into `my-cleanup-regexps`:

```
(defvar my-cleanup-regexps
  '(("^ +" "")
    (" +$" ""))
  "A list of (REGEXP TO-STRING).")

(defun my-cleanup-replace-regexp (regexp to-string)
  "Replace REGEXP with TO-STRING in the whole buffer."
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
    (replace-match to-string)))

(defun my-cleanup ()
  "Cleanup the whole buffer according to `my-cleanup-regexps'."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (r my-cleanup-regexps)
    (apply #'my-cleanup-replace-regexp r)))
```